# Header/ Title of date picker does not change when language change in android

Tags: android

[image]

Whenever I am changing language from french - > English body part of date picker change the language but header part remain the same in the old selected language.

That's my datepicker code

```
final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Date selectedDate = DateUtils.getDateFromDecomposedDate(dayOfMonth,monthOfYear, year);
                        tvSelectedDate.setText(DateUtils.dateToString(getContext(), selectedDate.getTime()));
                        tvSelectedDate.setTextAppearance(getContext(), R.style.datePickerSelectedDateStyle);

                        onDatePickerCustomViewListener.onDateSet((String)tvSelectedDate.getTag(), selectedDate);

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like title in DatePicker is controlled by application context, but content of DatePicker is by activity context. By changing an language programmatically, you are changing configuration only for actual context, so in your case names of months did changed, but title stay not. When you will change an language, you can change configuration for specific context

```
    private void changeLanguage(Context context) {
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        if (preferences.getString("language", "FR").equals("FR")) {

            conf.setLocale(new Locale("FR".toLowerCase()));
        } else {

            conf.setLocale(new Locale("EN".toLowerCase()));
        }
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    }
```

And call this for example in onResume() method

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        changeLanguage(this);
        changeLanguage(getApplicationContext());
    }
```

Otherwise you can controll languages via resources files, instead change it in runtime. Then an language in your app will be same like in your device.